# java and mysql load data infile misunderstanding

Tags: mysql

Thanks for viewing this. I need a little bit of help for this project that I am working on with MySql.

For part of the project I need to load a few things into a MySql database which I have up and running.

The info that I need, for each column in the table `Documentation`, is stored into text files on my hard drive.

For example, one column in the documentation table is "ports" so I have a ports.txt file on my computer with a bunch of port numbers and so on.

I tried to run this mysql script through phpMyAdmin which was

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\ports.txt" INTO TABLE `Documentation`(`ports`).
```

It ran successfully so I went to do the other load data i needed which was

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\vlan.txt' INTO TABLE `Documentation` (`vlans`)
```

This also completed successfully, but it added all the rows to the vlan column AFTER the last entry to the port column.

Why did this happen? Is there anything I can do to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why did this happen?

`LOAD DATA` inserts new rows into the specified table; it doesn't update existing rows.

> Is there anything I can do to fix this?

It's important to understand that MySQL doesn't guarantee that tables will be kept in any particular order.  So, after your first `LOAD`, the order in which the data were inserted may be lost & forgotten - therefore, one would typically relate such data *prior* to importing it (e.g. as columns of the same record within a single CSV file).

You *could* `LOAD` your data into temporary tables that each have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column and *hope* that such auto-incremented identifiers remain aligned between the two tables (MySQL makes absolutely no guarantee of this, but in your case you should find that each record is numbered sequentially from 1); once there, you could perform a query along the following lines:

```
INSERT INTO Documentation SELECT port, vlan FROM t_Ports JOIN t_Vlan USING (id);
```